# How to add a new name on a list of names from a txt file, and then add all names and display that number of names in a string

Tags: c#, arrays, append

1) Create new console application, with Visual Studio that you will call consolehw.

2)You will create a text file with that will have a list of at least 10 names of people. This file should be called names.txt and it should be placed inside the Debug folder of your consolehw application

3)  You will create a simple program to access this file using streams. You should first add your name the end of this file in a new line. After that, you will present in the console (Command Line if running in Windows or Terminal if running in Mac) all the names of the file and at the end of it, in a new line, a text that would say “There are X new participants in the seminar ” where X will be the number of lines (number of names) you read from the names.txt file after adding your name to it.

Notice that the first 10 names were already included in names.txt file. Your name should be included via the program and the final message that shows the X with the value of 11 new participants in the seminar.

Ive tried to append, and create arrays but I'm stumped on how to add the lines and display the number of names or lines in a message (string).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
namespace Consolehw
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string p = @"names.txt";
        using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(p))
        { sr.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "- Peter Lancer - "); sr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(p)); }

        String msg = "There are X new participants";
        Console.Write(msg);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

results were mentioned in summary as a guideline.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Try reading the new file line by line after appending your name, and keep track of how many lines you've read. That will give you X.

Comment: Seems like this is som kind of assignment (homework). You should put your code to read the file outside the scope of `using(StreamWriter ...` Then, just read all lines and count them so you can output the correct X based on the number of lines